# Box SDK authorize automatical to my account java

Tags: java, box-api, box

I'm working with Box Java SDK here (http://opensource.box.com/box-java-sdk/)

Now, I want to access to my account through API. The problem is:

I want to **access only to my account using username, password**, clientid, client secret to authorize. But follow the document, I must send request to https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize to get authorize_code and after that using SDK to authorize.

I want to ask about **any ways to authorize but did not do following there steps**? Because I only access to my account and I have username, password to access.

Please give me advice about it

Thanks

Comment: It is a little unclear where your confusion is so maybe try to restate your question. In order to use their oauth2 authorization flow, you will need to follow ALL of the steps in order to access their API.

Comment: @Suever, I want to access to my account through username and password to get access_token

Answer (score 0):

The API does not provide a way of accessing an account using just a username and password. You must go through the normal OAuth (or App Users) login process.

Comment: I know it but seem it so complicate when I only want to access to my account. So I have created class to auto get authenticate_code from box.